# Employee date of birth saved in column. I want to get the database data to split and get the dropdown boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

For a particular employee, I have his details stored in the database. These details also include the joining date which is stored in the database in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

In the front end, I have 3 dropdown lists one for DD another for MM and the third one for YYYY. All these 3 ddl's are filled up by appropriate values on load.

When I wish to see a particular record of the employee, I should get to see the joining date of employee in its respective ddl selected.

For example: in my database say date is 2000-01-01 for employee No 1, so when I select to see the details of employee No 1., the joining date should be displayed in my front end as:

- In my Day ddl I should see 01 selected
- in my Month ddl I should see 01 selected
- and my Year ddl I should see 2000 selected

Please can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why dropdownlist? Do you want to update the joining date later? And is this webform or MVC?

Comment: What technology are you using? and what platform? web or mobile or what?

Answer (score 0):

get the year, month and day from the date string by splitting

```
string dbdate ="1989-10-25";//yyyy-mm-dd
string[] parts = dbdate.Split('-');
string year =parts[0];
string month=parts[1];
string day=parts[2];

// now you can set the selected value of each dropdown 
// make sure before set selectedvalue you have load the items 
ddlYear.SelectedValue = year ;
ddlMonath.SelectedValue = month;
ddlDay.SelectedValue = day;
```

Comment: string birthday = dr[7].ToString();
                string[] parts = birthday.Split('-');
                string day = parts[0];
                string month = parts[1];
                string year = parts[2];


                DropDownListday.SelectedValue = day;
                DropDownListmonth.SelectedValue = month;
                DropDownListyear.SelectedValue = year;